# Forms Authentication (restrict an area)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, forms-authentication, roles, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm developing an website using asp.net mvc with MySQL and I need to make a simple restrict area for the user update some informations in website. So, I had created an area in mvc application called "Admin", and I know how to protect it using Forms authentication and Autorize attribute! It works fine, but in each controller of my area I have to set the Autorize attribute to protected them. Is there any way to protected all Area in Web.config? How can I do that?

Thanks

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **must not** use Web.config location-based authorization in an MVC application.  Doing so will lead to security vulnerabilities in your site.

The easiest way to get the behavior you're looking for is to have an AdminBaseController which has an [Authorize] attribute on it, then have each controller in your Admin area subclass this  type directly.  The attribute will flow from the base type to the subclassed types.

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? Because this solution does not seems very elegant, I will need to make sure all my controllers subclass the base controller. I might as well just add the required attribute to all the controllers.

Comment: @RosdiKasim, you can add the authorize filter to the list of global filters if you want.  Then every controller gets it automatically.  If you do this, put the [AllowAnonymous] attribute on individual controllers or actions to have them opt-out of the global authorize filter.

Comment: can you please tell me why it would lead to vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

A bit off your question as you want to use Web.config, but you can use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp) (an aspect oriented framework) to inject attributes on methods.